# error while installing sonarLint eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

When I am trying to install sonarLint in eclipse Juno from market place . Its giving following error.Unable to read repository at https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org/content.xml.
Received fatal alert: protocol_version.Please refer screenshot.Any Idea how can install sonarlint for eclipse or is there any other plugin available for same purpose.

[image]

Comment: The Eclipse Marketplace points to the old location of the update site which has moved. Does _Help > Install New Software..._ work with [`https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/4.0.0/`](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/4.0.0/) work for you? By the way, Eclipse Juno is pretty old. Please upgrade.

Comment: I am  getting same error while doing this way too. Unable to read repository at https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/4.0.0/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/4.0.0/content.xml.
Received fatal alert: protocol_version...

Comment: What kind of organization uses outdated software? For security reasons, software should always be up-to-date. Your issue might be caused by a too old Java version unable to open `https://...` or maybe you are behind a proxy which blocks HTTPS. Please add the whole error message to your question and tell which Java version do you use.

Comment: yes, i think there is a proxy which is blocking URL. Let me check and then will revert back accordingly.

Comment: @ShilpiJaiswal Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @howlger Getting the same error. Error logs 
`eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  xxxx
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product xxxx -keyring /Users/xxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

Created Time: 2019-06-18 14:09:14 
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
Wed Jun 19 16:05:05 PDT 2019
Unable to read repository at https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org/content.xml.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
`

Comment: @R11G The locations of the update site can be edited in _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Java 8 or above installed. 
Sonarlist in marketplace clearly states so "Java 8 is required to run SonarLint". 
I had same issue and it was resolved when I updated java from v7 to v8.

Link to the sonarlint marketplace page 
[Sonarlint](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint)